# Mutual independence in the Local Lemma

Tags: probabilistic-method

The statement of the local lemma relies on dependency graphs.

Given events $A_1, \dots A_n$ a dependency graph $G = ([n], E)$ on the $A_i$ satisfies that for all $i$, we have that $A_i$ is mutually independent of $\{A_j : \{i, j\} \not\in E\}$

What exactly does this mutual independence assumption mean on a set of events? For instance, say we have $A_1$ and $\{A_2, A_3\}$. Does this mean that $A_1, A_2, A_3$ are mutually independent or something slightly different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The traditional mutual independence assumption is that conditioning on any combination of the $A_j$ and their negations does not change the probability of $A_i$. Formally, if $S,T \subseteq \{j : ij \notin E\}$, then we want
$$
    \Pr\left[A_i \,\middle|\, \left(\bigwedge_{j \in S} A_j\right) \land \left(\bigwedge_{j \in T} \neg A_j\right) \right] = \Pr[A_i].
$$
I'm pretty sure this is equivalent to asking that $\{A_i\} \cup \{A_j : ij \notin E\}$ are mutually independent.

The typical thing to watch out for is events which are related to but pairwise independent from $A_i$, because they can still affect the probability of $A_i$ when we combine several of them.

For example, take a triangle graph on vertices $\{1,2,3\}$ and give it a random red-blue vertex coloring; let $A_{ij}$ be the event that vertices $i$ and $j$ get the same coloring. Then any two of these events are independent. However, $\Pr[A_{12}] = \frac12$ while $\Pr[A_{12} \mid A_{13} \land A_{23}] = 1$. (Similarly, $\Pr[A_{12} \mid \neg A_{13} \land \neg A_{23}] = 1$: the negations don't help.) So we do need edges in the dependency graph. (At least two of them.)

We're definitely fine in the common setting where we choose random variables $(X_1, X_2, \dots, X_N)$, have each event $A_i$ be determined by a subset of these random variables, and put an edge $ij$ in the dependency graph whenever $A_i$ and $A_j$ share some of the random variables that they're determined by.

---

It's also been observed (by Erdős and Spencer in 1990, in their paper *Lopsided Lovász Local Lemma and Latin transversals*) that the condition we actually use in the proof of the local lemma is weaker, and we can make use of this. Specifically, what we *really* want is a "lopsidependency graph" $G$ satisfying the property that
$$
    \Pr\left[A_i \,\middle|\, \bigwedge_{j \in S} \neg A_j \right] \le \Pr[A_i]
$$
for any $i, S$ such that $ij \notin E(G)$ for all $j \in S$.